# Angular2 boilerplate npm-start not working

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-start

I am new to Angular2 and trying to setup the environment with the boilerplate code https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/angular-2-beta-boilerplate.

My dependencies installed fine with `npm install` but when I run `npm start` I start to get the below statements. I don't think its an error but its hard to figure out as to what it really means.

```
$ npm start

> angular2-boilerplate@1.0.0 start C:\Users\user\desktop\angboiler\angular-2-beta-boilerplate
> concurrent "npm run gulp" "npm run lite"
```

I tried installing `run lite`, `concurrently` separately but that didn't work. I even ran `npm update -g && npm install -g concurrently lite-server typescript`
 to make sure i have stuffs updated to make it work but still no progress.

I have: typescript 1.8 version node 4.4.5 version running.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, perhaps you would be interested in using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), which seems to be the official boilerplate for Angular 2.